# http-outbound-gateway sets wrong content-type header

Tags: spring-integration

we migrated from SIv3.x to SIv4.0.4 and found that now the http-outbound-gateway sets wrongly the content-type header. Instead of setting it like this content-type, it sets it like contentType. Searching around I found that this may be because now SI uses Spring Messaging clases where this attribute is named contentType.

public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "contentType";

Is there a way to set correctly this content-type in the http-outbound or maybe before using an object-to-json-transformer?

thanks in advance
Regards
Guzmán

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I understand your point and it is really a bug, which we missed when migrate to the Spring Messaging.

Please, raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) ticket on the matter - and we have to map `contentType` message header to the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Right now as a workaround you can `re-map` it manually:

```
<header-enricher>
   <header name="#{T(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders).CONTENT_TYPE}" expression="headers[#{T(org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders).CONTENT_TYPE}]"/>
</header-enricher>
```

And not before `<obeject-to-json-transformer>`, but after and just before `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`

Comment: thanks for the workaround Artem! I added to JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3508.